# How to take difference of list based on multiple filters in ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-filter

I have a list of objects

```
List1:
- name: Rule1
  description: Description1
  sources:
    ip_addresses:
      - any
- name: Rule2
  description: Description2
  sources:
    ip_addresses:
      - any
- name: Rule3
  description: Description3
  sources:
    ip_addresses:
      - any
- name: Rule4
  description: Description4
  sources:
    ip_addresses:
      - any
```

I wanted to create a new list by omitting rules with certain descriptions, I was able to do it for single description by using:

```
List2: "{{
  List1 | difference(
  List1
  | selectattr('description')
  | selectattr('description', 'match', Description1)
  | list) }}"
```

I am not able to figure out how to do so for multiple description, for example if we need to omit both Rule1 and Rule2. One way I was able to do so was creating List2 after omitting Rule1 and then creating a List3 where by using a similar filter on List2.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the descriptions you want to omit. For example

```yaml
    omit_desc:
      - Description1
      - Description2
```

Then the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        List2: "{{ List1|rejectattr('description', 'in', omit_desc)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: List2
```

gives

```yaml
  List2:
  - description: Description3
    name: Rule3
    sources:
      ip_addresses:
      - any
  - description: Description4
    name: Rule4
    sources:
      ip_addresses:
      - any
```

---

- See filter [rejectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#rejectattr)
- See test [in](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#in)

Comment: I tried this I'm getting a error saying : no test named 'in'